# I want to get full path when I'm accessing a file stored in .jar file. How to do this?

Tags: java, eclipse

I'm new in java. I'm using eclipse to develop in java. I have a folder in project directory named "include", and in that folder, I've a file named "trial.jpg". I want to get the full path (with drive name, folder name and jar name after compiled). Please help me. Thank you.

Comment: Why?  `File f = new File("./include/trial.jpg"); f.getAbsolutePath();` will get you the full path

Comment: You are probably looking for [Class.getResource](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getResource(java.lang.String)) but it returns a URL because a `File` does not make sense in the case of a resource embedded in a Jar file.

Comment: In output string, an extra dot (.) is added (e.g. D:\SamplePro\.\include\trial.jpg).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the path to your jar by doing:

```
return new File(MyClass.class.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation().toURI().getPath());
```

as suggested in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/320595/1528777).

But, if you're trying to access the 'trial.jpg' from your code, you don't need a full path to it. It should already be in your classpath and you should be able to reference it directly.

Something along the lines of

```
InputStream is = this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("include/trial.jpg");
```